# How to get monthwise sum from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Table **Transaction**(Id, DateTime, Debit, Credit)

I want a monthwise sum of Debit and Credit.

What is a good option to retrieve monthwise result?

Sample Output:

```
Month    Id  Debit Credit
January   1  200    70
January   2  400    80
February  1  400    90
February  2  300    50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below script with GROUP BY function. I have added YEAR in consideration other wise same month from different year will count as same month.

```
SELECT YEAR(DateTime), 
MONTH(DateTime), 
Id, 
SUM(Debit) total_debit,
SUM(Credit) total_credit
FROM your_table
GROUP BY YEAR(DateTime), MONTH(DateTime), Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply Group by clause to SQL Query

```
group by month(DateTime),Year(DateTime)
```